# What is the most annoying feature (or lack of feature) you have found in the Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I am starting with the Entity Framework. It sounds great. But I am wondering if I should watch out for some weakness somewhere. Any experience there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to start prefixing these questions with the version you are talking about.  A good amount of the annoyances have been fixed in the upcoming version in .NET 4.0.

Here is what I would say after working with the first version for about 6 months using a decent size DB in sql 2k8(40+ tables, several tables with close to 1M rows, and decent amount of traffic)

- **Lack of Foreign key properties**. Meaning if I want to know or work with just the id of a related table I have to load the actual entity. (fixed in next version)
- **Utter lack of an easy outer join** like linq to sql has when using **DefaultIfEmpty**.  Fixed in next version.
- **Generated Sql is less than optimal**  This seems to be fixed in next version as well
- Very difficult to abstract from your code for **testability** and for use in **multi tiered environments**, but it can be done.  This can also be classified as the POCO problem that also has been resolved.

There are more, but these are my top ones.

Overall I would use it again, but if you are starting from scratch please save yourself some pain and **wait for the latest version or start using the beta if you can.**

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [walkthroughs for Entity Framework 4.0 useful](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/tags/Entity+Framework/default.aspx).  All of the new features discussed are annoying emissions from the currently released version for someone.

I found the new TDD/testability features and T4 code generation features especially interesting.

Answer (score 1):

About EF1:

- Generated SQL is horrible. It multiples joins, it is 10x bigger than it could. I had a simple query, but with a lot of joins and generating this query by EF (not executing) was slowing down significantly my application. No, I couldn't use precompiled query. I used view to cope with it. SQL Profiler was helpful.
- Primary keys in views are not recognized properly. You have to change edmx file by hand when you import view or doing schema refresh.
- You can design entities from database in graphical manner, update model from database, but it doesn't always work good, specially when you change field types or foreign keys.
- You can't update one table in model, always have to update whole model from db.
- You can't define base class for your entities, it is already defined (EntityObject). You can use interfaces, because classes are defined as partial.
- No POCO, entity classes are strongly connected to framework.
- You can set foreign key by EntityReference.EntityKey, but when you have EntityCollection, prepare for round trip to db. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

I am finding the POCO objects and model-first design in the EF4 beta very sexy.

Comment: I guess what you consider to be sexy differs from mine... :)   I will say it is exciting, but not in a "waiting for my cialis to kick in while sitting in matching bath tubs on a green field kinda way"